# Recursive in BNF grammar

Tags: c, recursion, compiler-construction, bnf, recursive-descent

Well, I'm not sure how I should write a function using recursive descent parse to parse a grammer like the below. Actually, I'm not sure if I was doing right it...

BNF:

```
 A : B | A '!'
 B : '[' ']'
```

pseudo-code:

```
f()
{
   if(tok is B) 
      parse_b();
      return somethingB
   else if(????) how will I know if it's start of A or I don't need to?
      x = f();
      parse_c();
      return somethingA
}
```

I was doing this (no check to determine if it's an A but I feel there's something wrong with it):

```
f()
{
   if(tok is B) 
      parse_b();
      return somethingB
   else
      x = f();
      parse_c();
      return somethingA
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16165352/why-cant-a-ll-grammar-be-left-recursive

Comment: It is not clear which of your symbols are tokens and which are non-terminals. If only B and C are tokens, then you need to either refactor the grammar or use more lookahead than you do.

Comment: didierc: I will check out this. @n.m.: is `A : B | A '!'` more clear?

Comment: For details on how to build a recursive descent parser, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2336769/120163

Comment: ... or restructure your parser. Write down several strings that belong to the language and see how your function would process them.

Comment: Hm. Is B a token? If not, where are its rules? If yes... why are you calling it B?

Comment: Take a look at Pratt parsing: http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2011/03/19/pratt-parsers-expression-parsing-made-easy/

Comment: I added B rules. I will check out this links

Comment: I don't understand how the restructure would be performed... could you give an example from this grammar? `foo:  '(' ')' | foo '[' ']'` (now I will really check the links)

Comment: @IraBaxter: You answer solved my question. In special, how to deal with `L  =  A |  L A ;` (exactly what I tried put in my question). If you post as answer here I will accept. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my SO answer to another similar question on [details on how to build a recursive descent parser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2336769/120163).

In particular it addresses the structure of the parser, and how you can pretty much derive it by inspecting your grammar rules, including handling lists.