# Generating the LL(1) parsing table for the given CFG

Tags: parsing, context-free-grammar, ll-grammar

The CFG is as following :

```
S -> SD|SB
B -> b|c
D -> a|dB
```

The method which I tried is as following:

I removed non-determinism from the first production (`S->SD|SB`) by left-factoring method.

So, the CFG after applying left-factoring is as following:

```
S -> SS'
S'-> D|B
B -> b|c
D -> a|dB
```

I need to find the *first* of `S` for the production i.e. `S -> SS'`
in order to proceed further. Could some one please help or advise?

Comment: You cannot solve this using *left-factoring*. If you analyze the structure however, you see that it is equivalent with `S -> S'S`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot convert this grammar that way into an LL(1) parser: the grammar is [*left recursive*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16165352/67579), you thus will have to perform [*left recursion removal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser#Left_recursion_removal.5B4.5D). The point is that you can perform the following trick: since the only rule for `S` is `S -> SS'` and `S ->` (epsilon), it means that you simply reverse the order, and thus introduce the rule `S -> S'S`. So now the grammar is:

```
S -> S'S
S'-> D|B
B -> b|c
D -> a|dB
```

Now we can construct *first*: *first(B)={b,c}*, *first(D)={a,d}*, *first(S')={a,b,c,d}* and *first(S)={a,b,c,d}*.

Comment: Thank you, but I have a doubt which is:

Comment: @alisa: please [`[edit]`](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34374300/edit) your question.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have a doubt. As you mentioned "The point is that you can perform the following trick: since the only rule for S is S -> SS' and S -> (epsilon), it means that you simply reverse the order, and thus introduce the rule S -> S'S." Could you please also elaborate this? Also S->(epsilon) is not a production in the original given grammar, how could it be possible to add it? Please advise.

Comment: @alisa: most grammars have this rule implicitly: otherwise your `S` would generate an infinite amount of `S'`es.